# Posting a default value with serializer in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to post a default value.

In plain English, this is how I want it to work:

1. If data has no "tag" field (s)
2. Check to see if tag "none" exists (for 'owner')
3. If tag "none" exists, create the m2m
4. If tag "none' doesn't exist, create the tag none (for 'owner')

My post data will **not** contain the field `tag` in the JSON data being posted.

**This code works perfectly EXCEPT when there is no `tag` field**

When there is no tag field, it tells me 'tag field is required'

## Example data being posted

`{title: "Testing"}`

## Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField("Tag level", null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)v

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
```

## Serializer

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        ordering = ('-created',)
        fields = ('title', 'pk', 'tag')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        owner = self.context['request'].user
        item = Item.objects.create(owner=owner, **validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tag_data['owner'] = owner
            tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])

            if not tag_data:
                Tag.objects.get_or_create(tag_name="None")

            if tag_qs.exists():
                tag = tag_qs.first()
            else:
                tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
            item.tag.add(tag)
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `default=None` in your tag field of ItemSerializer.

Your ItemSerializer should now looks like:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(default=None, many=True, read_only=False)
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Nope, this did not work. It stopped the "tag field required" error, but did not set the default "tag field" it needed. Please give another suggestion

Comment: @Ycon , instead of `default=None` put `required=False` please

Comment: No luck. I have used `require=False` instead, but it gives me a key error. Will `get_or_create` actually create a tag named "None" if it does not exist? This is the traceback http://dpaste.com/1BYMTDT

Comment: I see the issue. It is looking for "tags_data" which does not exist. As you can see, the example data is not posting "tag" at all. What is a smart way around this? An else/if for the entire create?